# Why is this code not writing anything to the file

Tags: java

Why is this code not writing anything to the file?
It returns TRUE though, but nothing goes in the file.
No exception thrown either.

This is the method. I call it like this in main()

```
boolean b = AppendFile( f, " hello world" );


    public folder = "dir/";
    String f= "ttest"; // no file extension. A plain text file 

    public boolean AppendFile( String f, String s ){
    try{
    int err=1;

    File file = new File( folder + f );
    if (!file.exists()) { return false;  }

    s= s.replace( "NULL", " " );
    s= s.replace( "null", " " );
    s= s.replace( "Null", " " );


    s= s.trim() +"\r\n";

    FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter( file.getName(),true);
    BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter( fileWritter );
    br.write( s );
    br.close();
    return true;

    }catch(Exception e){ return false; }

    }//end
```

Comment: This code `boolean b = AppendFile( f, " hello world" );


    public folder = "dir/";
    String f= "ttest"; // no file extension. A plain text file ` does not make sense

Comment: Why would you completely ignore an exception?

Comment: If it returns true, then something is written to the file. Are you sure you're looking at the right file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error. Thanks @Andreas
I should remove the .getName() from this line:

FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter( file.getName(),true);

Thanks :)